# In the group ring $\mathbb{Z}_p [G]$, what elements satisfy $(\sum a_g g)^p = \sum a_g g^p$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings

Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Preferably I would want to know this for a general group $G$, but I have been concentrating on the case $G = (\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ as a starting point.

I have also looked at the case when $\sum a_g g$ has finite order and I deduced that this implies $\sum (a_g g)^p = \sum a_g g^p$ (I wrote $\sum a_g g$ as $\sum p^i a_{g,i} g$ so we now have $1 = (\sum p^i a_{g,i} g)^k$. By equating coefficients we see that $\sum a_{g,0} g$ is both a unit and a zero-divisor unless $\sum a_{g,i} g = 0$ for all $i>0$. Finally we just equate coefficients of $(\sum a_g g)^p = \sum a_g g^p$.)

Any help on the general case or special case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short question: Is your ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ or are you talking about the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: ... which leads to a longer question: Why are there so many authors who write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? *sigh*

Comment: @HeinrichD: because in many parts of mathematics, it's the standard notation

Comment: @Bernte: It is the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Quick notational comment, I've found that writing $\mathbb{Z}_{/n}$ for the integers modulo $n$ is both unambiguous and unobtrusive.

Comment: @DouglasLind Not entirely unambiguous I think - it might be understood to mean $\frac1n\mathbb Z$ :)

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: That's sort of a content free answer, given that HeinrichD's question is basically "why is it standard notation?" :)

Comment: Incidentally, why not $\left( \sum_{g}a_{g}g \right)^{p}= \left( \sum_{g} a_{g}^{p}g^{p} \right)$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ could also be considered as ambiguous for being understood as $\frac1n\mathbb{Z}$ (sorry for idle chatting!)

Comment: @YCor less so since the last $\mathbb Z$ would be redundant with that understanding (sorry too :D)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე you're right, anyway I'll erase this comment (and the present one too!)

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: I had been working on a map defined in Robert Oliver's book on [Whitehead Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/whitehead-groups-of-finite-groups/FEEEE48B62CAB93D3631744C457E391B) (Definition 6.1):

Let $F$ be an unramifted extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $R$ is the ring of integers. Their is an endomorphism from $R[G]$ to $R[G]$ defined as $\sum a_g g \rightarrow \sum \psi (a_g) g^p$ where $\psi$ if the Frobentus automorphism in $Gal(F/ \mathbb{Q}_p)$, but this turns out to be the identity when $R= \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 3):

For a finite Abelian group $G$ you can use the linear characters of $G$ ( and an extension $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\omega]$ for a suitable root of unity) to translate the problem as follows: there are $|G|$ different homomorphisms from $G$  to $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\omega]^{\times},$ (the linear characters of $G$) and your equation is satisfied in $G$ if and only if $\left( \sum_{g} a_{g} \lambda (g)\right)^{p} = \sum_{g}a_{g} \lambda(g^{p})$ for every choice of such a linear character $\lambda.$

For a general finite group $G,$ use of the augmentation ideal of the group ring gives the necessary condition that $\sum_{g}a_{g}$ is one of the $p$ solutions of $x^{p} = x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}.$

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ has no $p$-torsion, then the Jacobian matrix of this system of equations is invertible modulo $p$ (the derivative of the left side vanishes mod $p$, and the derivative of the right side is a permutation matrix). Hence each mod $p$ solution lifts to a unique solution over $\mathbb Z_p$.

If in addition $G$ is abelian, then every function mod $p$ is a solution.

We can calculate the solutions in this case using Geoff Robinson's answer. Because in this case composing with the $p$th power is a permutation with the character, the Fourier coefficient associated to each character is a $q-1$ root of unity or zero, where $q$ is the order of the finite field over which that character, modulo $p$, is defined.  So we can calculate the lift by taking an arbitrary mod $p$ function on $G$, applying the Fourier transform, obtaining a function on $\hat{G}$, taking Techmuller lifts, and applying the inverse Fourier transform.

EDIT : I think my first sentence is actually only true when $G$ is abelian and $p$-torsion free. We can write the derivative as a sum of $p$ terms, which are identical if $g$ is commutative.